# Кто должен покупать платные плагины Wordpress - заказчик или фрилансер?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Условно, клиенту нужно интегрировать свою систему учета с интернет-магазином на Wordpress. Есть платный плагин, который обладает таким функционалом. Кто его должен оплачивать - заказчик или фрилансер? Как при этом вы общаетесь с клиентом, если платить должен он?

Просто, прочитав условия использования некоторых таких плагинов, я обнаружил, что почти везде там есть приписка о том, что купленный плагин должен использоваться только для одного проекта.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Кому он нужен, тот и платит. Если заказчик говорит мне нужен функционал, но данный плагин не нужен, а разраб не может сам подобный сделать - то разраб пусть покупает))

Comment: Как договоритесь, на мой взгляд. Формально при такой приписке - Заказчик. Но да, вопрос как стоимость работы изменится от этого.

Comment: Тут решать нечего - конечно заказчик. У него должны быть доступы к производителю вне зависимости от исполнителя. А финансовый вопрос решается очень просто - написать своё аналог существующего во много раз дороже. Только полный идиот захочет многократно переплатить за рукописную поделку с сомнительной поддержкой (миллионы случаев когда исполнитель слинял после сдачи проекта или заказчику показалось "дорого обслуживать" и он решил что сам справится).